# Express - mysql query results not rendering

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm making webform where the user enters a serial number, and information about an item with the corresponding serial number is displayed.

The database query is successful, but `res.render()` isn't rendering the results.

app.js

```
//ibutton page, displayed after clicking link
app.get('/ibuttons', function (req, res){
    res.render('ibutton');
});

app.post('/ibuttons/view/', function (req, res){

let query = ('SELECT serialNum, lotNumber, dateCode, model FROM iButton WHERE serialNum = ?');
db.query(query, [req.body.serialNumber], function (err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
    res.render('ibutton', {
        ibuttons: results
    });

  });
});
```

ibutton.ejs

```
<% include partials/ibuttonHeader %>
<h1>iButton Information</h1>
<form method = "POST" action="/ibuttons/view">
    <label>Enter your iButton's Serial Number</label><br>
    <input type ="test" name="serialNumber">
    <input type ="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div>
    <table>
        <% ibuttons.forEach(function(ibutton){ %>
            <tr><%ibutton.serialNum%></tr>
            worked
        <% }) %> 
    </table>
</div>
```

After entering a serial number thats in the base and clicking "submit", on /ibutton/view "worked" is displayed which means that the `forEach` looped through something, and the console prints out the query results, but the information is not shown on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ibutton.ejs

```
<tr><%ibutton.serialNum%></tr>
```

should be

```
<tr><%=ibutton.serialNum%></tr>
```

I forgot the '=' which is needed for variables.